# SSRS - I want to filter on data used in an Average

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Sorry - I'm quite new to SSRS and floundering about.

I want to average some values over 3 years worth of data but I don't want to include 2020 in my average.

so currently the Value is [Avg(L3VAValueAdded)] - which works for all years - but includes 2020  but I need to be something like [Avg(L3VAValueAdded) where year <> 2020] or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the actual expression that you currently have it will probably look something like this...

```
=AVG(Fields!L3VAValueAdded.Value)
```

An interesting feature of the `AVG()` function is that it does not include `NULL` values so we can use this to our advantage.

Change your expression to

```
=AVG(IIF(Fields!myYearField.Value) = 2020, Nothing, Fields!L3VAValueAdded.Value))
```

Obviously swap out the `myYearField` name for the correct field containing your year. This assume the "year" field is numeric, if it is a string then put 2020 in quotes.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering Alan - I have replaced my field name for the year which is called Description  but now I am getting a red wiggly line under that part from the IFF to the first closed bracket.   =AVG(IIF(Fields!Description.Value) = 2020, Nothing, Fields!L3VAValueAdded.Value)      Description is correct as it in the drop down field list so I don't know why it doesn't like it?

Comment: =AVG(IIF(Fields!Description.Value = 2020, Nothing, Fields!L3VAValueAdded.Value))

Comment: Ah sorry, missed off the closing parenthesis!

Comment: If this answered your question, can you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark under the vote up/down buttons). This helps others looking for accepted solutions to similar problems in the future. Thanks.